# Gremlin get elementMap() for vertices and valueMap() for edges when used with .bothE().otherV().path()

Tags: gremlin

Assume we want to retrieve all in-coming and out-going edges for some specific vertex and have the result include from_vertex, edge and to_vertex.

The following should give us the result.

```bash
g.V(1).bothE().otherV().path()
==>path[v[...], e[...][...-...->...], v[...]]
```

The following adds `.elementMap()` for vertices and edge.

```bash
g.V(1).bothE().otherV().path().by(__.elementMap())
==>path[{...} {...} {...}]
```

Now, we want to retrieve the properties, where we want to use `.elementMap()` for the vertices and `.valueMap()` for the edges. My first guess is the following

```java
g.V(1).
  bothE().as("edges").
  otherV().as("nodes").
  path().
  by(__.select("nodes").elementMap().select("edges").valueMap())
```

which just returns

```bash
==>path[null, null, null]
```

Any ideas?
Further, how to get the path output for an entire subtree starting from some specific vertex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your path will be an alternating list of node-edge-node etc. To get the desired results you just need to use two `by` modulators.

```java
g.V(1).
  bothE().
  otherV().
  path().
    by(elementMap()).
    by(valueMap())
```